# Python BeautifulSoup Extracting Titile Web Crawler

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to extract the title from an image. I have managed to extract the `url` but not sure how to code the extraction of the title of the image.

**[Code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE06m.png)**

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

def trade_spider(max_pages): 
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'http://www.gurstree.com.au/s—cars—vans—utes/melbourne/page—' + str(page) + '/c1832013001317'
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'ad—listing_title—link'}):
            href = 'http://www.gumtree.com.au/' + link.get('href')
            print(href)
        page += 1 

trade_spider(1)
```

**[The HTML is:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgDQ8.png)**

```
<a itemprop="url" class="ad-listing__thumb-link" name="1124692138" href="/s-ad/derrimut/cars-vans-utes/2015-toyota-86-coupe-12-month-warranty-/1124692138" data-ref="searchTopAd">
  <span id="r-image-TOP_AD-1124692138" title="2015 Toyota 86 Coupe **12 MONTH WARRANTY** Derrimut Brimbank Area Preview" class="j-responsive-image ad-listing__thumb" data-index="1">...</span>
</a>
```

The first line is the `href` but I want to get the `title` as per the `span` block of HTML highlighted.

Thanks!

Comment: post your code rather than image

Comment: can u add url here? hard to get from code image

Answer (score 0):

```
link.span.get('title')
```

use `.` to find next `span` and get `title`

use [regex](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) to match string in the addribute:

```
import re    
soup.find('span', id=re.compile(r'r-image'))
```

Comment: Ok I managed to get it to work with link.get('title'). If I wanted to use the 'id' reference and 'r-image-TOP_AD-1124692138', how could I use this if the numbers at the end of -Top_AD- are changed for every post?

Comment: Awesome thank you!